# UTF-8 Encoding Error when Running External Groovy Script from Grails

Tags: java, grails, groovy

I am trying to call an external Groovy script from within a Grails application.  I have the following code:

```
def initialSize = 4096
def outStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(initialSize)
def errStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(initialSize)
def process ="groovy -cp src/groovy/ src/groovy/externalscript.groovy ".execute()
process.consumeProcessOutput(outStream, errStream)
process.waitFor()
println 'out:\n' + outStream
println 'err:\n' + errStream
println process.exitValue()
```

However, I get the following exception:

Error occurred during initialization of VM java.nio.charset.IllegalCharsetNameException: "UTF-8" at java.nio.charset.Charset.checkName(Charset.java:284) at java.nio.charset.Charset.lookup2(Charset.java:458) at java.nio.charset.Charset.lookup(Charset.java:437) at java.nio.charset.Charset.defaultCharset(Charset.java:579) at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.forOutputStreamWriter(StreamEncoder.java:37) at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.(OutputStreamWriter.java:94) at java.io.PrintStream.(PrintStream.java:100) at java.lang.System.initializeSystemClass(System.java:1092)

The script works fine outside of Grails and I am not sure where the encoding issue is coming from. I have tried saving the externalscript.groovy as UTF-8 but I run into the same issue.

Comment: are you running this application from NetBeans IDE? else can you run it froom NetBeans IDE.NetBeans latest version support Grails and Groovy

Comment: Kevin, you need to accept an answer. I would look at Michael's

Answer (score 3):

The exception is thrown because the plateform default encoding for the child JVM somehow ended up being `"UTF-8"` *including the quotation marks*, which is not a legal charset name. It has nothing to do with the script itself, but with the way Grails spawns the child JVM.

Do you have something like

```
file.encoding="UTF-8"
```

anywhere in your Grails configuration? Or code that sets the `file.encoding` system property?

Comment: THANK YOU, Michael! That just saved our day at the office, trying to figure out why Glassfish refused to accept UTF-8. -Dfile.encoding="UTF-8" worked in the shell (since the shell removes the quotes), but not in the GF config. I finally replicated the error after reading your answer by setting -Dfile.encoding=\"UTF-8\" in the shell. Simply removing the quotes solved the case.

Answer (score 0):

What if you change your output streams to:

```
def outStream = new StringWriter(initialSize)
def errStream = new StringWriter(initialSize)
```